How to generate lensed light animations like this?
How can one generate the projection simulation effect in the following video (from Apple's webpage (minus the logo of course)).
I would like to be able to create a similar-looking shader animation in WL code, with control over the colors, blur amount, and shapes in a Manipulate.

First-Worst attempt:
ManipulateVideo[
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[
   Table[{Blend[{Blue, Pink, LightBlue, Purple}, Mod[i, 1]], 
     Opacity[0.05], Glow[Blend[{Blue, Pink, LightBlue}, Mod[i, 1]]], 
     Disk[{Cos[2 u] Sin[i], Sin[u] Cos[i]} + {Cos[u^2] Sin[2 t + i], 
        Sin[Cos[2 u]] Cos[2 t + i]}, 
      0.1 Sin[u] + 0.2 Cos[u] Sin[t + i]]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/30}, {t, 
     0, 2 Pi, Pi/40}], Background -> Black, 
   ImagePadding -> Scaled[.2], ImageSize -> 500], {{u, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}], 
 FrameRate -> 10]



The Apple video looks like the maker might have used some kind of entwined Lorenz attractors that then get zoomed and spun.  Just an idea to try.

Also on Research Gate.

That's an amazing first attempt.
